# Are there countably many infinities?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

$\aleph_0$, $\aleph_1, \aleph_2$ and so on are indexed by a natural number so shouldn't there be countably many infinities?

Comment: Those aren't the only infinities...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'res an infinite number of infinities?

Answer (score 9):

After you exhaust all the $\aleph_n$, you still have $\aleph_\omega$ which is a cardinality larger than all the $\aleph_n$'s. Then you have $\aleph_{\omega+n}$, for integer $n$, and so on.

And you have many many many more cardinals. In fact, for every ordinal $\alpha$ you have cardinal $\aleph_\alpha$. Since there are uncountable ordinals, there are *at least* uncountably many cardinals. But in fact, the collection of cardinals does not make a set, it is a proper class.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that there is an $\aleph_\alpha$ for each ordinal $\alpha$?

Comment: Sure, by definition of the $\aleph$ numbers. $\aleph_0=\omega_0$; $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the least ordinal which is not of cardinality $\leq\aleph_\alpha$ (often denoted by $\omega_\alpha$) and if $\delta$ is a limit then $\aleph_\delta=\sup_{\beta<\delta}\aleph_\delta$.

Comment: But I don't see how you can get more than countably many cardinalities by that procedure.

Comment: Let's do this backwards, what's bothering you in this argument?

Comment: Let's start with $\aleph_0$. Now with the $\alpha+1$ rule, I can generate $\aleph_1$, $\aleph_2$ and so on. Basically, everything $\aleph_n$, $n\in\mathbb N$. With the limit rule I then get $\aleph_\omega$. Then I get $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ etc., then again with the limit rule $\aleph_{2\omega}$, and indeed $\aleph_{m\omega+n}$. I even see how you can extend that to arbitrary polynomials of $\omega$. But those are still countably many ordinals, and thus countably many cardinals associated to them. So, how do you get beyond countability?

Comment: Well, if $\alpha>0$ is an ordinal, and $\aleph_\beta$ was defined for all $\beta<\alpha$, then either $\alpha=\beta+1$ in which case $\aleph_\alpha$ exists of course, of $\alpha$ is a limit and then $\aleph_\alpha$ is the supremum of all the previous ones. After all "countable polynomials" you have $\varepsilon_0$, but you agreed that $\aleph_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$ exists, so $\aleph_{\varepsilon_0}$ exists too. And the party continues.

Comment: Well, I didn't yet agree that $\aleph_\alpha$ exists for *all* $\alpha<\epsilon_0$ exist. For that I first need an argument that *all* countable ordinals are reachable through the addition/limit process.

Comment: I have time, let me know when you're done! ;-) But again, this is really by induction. If $\alpha$ is the least one where $\aleph_\alpha$ doesn't exist, then either it's a successor, but then $\aleph_{\alpha-1}$ exists, and so $\aleph_\alpha$ is by definition its successor cardinal (and that cardinal exists); or $\alpha$ is a limit, in which case $\aleph_\alpha$ is just the supremum of the previous $\aleph$'s, all of which already exists. Therefore $\aleph_\alpha$ exists for all $\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Thank you!