# Is the set of aleph numbers countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If I write the set of aleph numbers in this way $\{\aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, \aleph_3, \dots\}$ it seems obvious to me that this set is countable, because aleph numbers have integer coefficients. However, maybe we are using the wrong notation for aleph numbers: how do we know that aleph numbers are really countable?

I think my question can be rephrased like this: what is the cardinality of the set $\{\mathbb{N}, \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})), \mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))), \dots\}$, where $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ represents the power set of $\mathbb{N}$? How do I prove it?

Comment: The aleph numbers are indexed by ordinals, and therefore are not even a set : they are all the infinite cardinals.

Comment: This is a good question, which has been asked several times before.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517173/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472332/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8013/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11040/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715321

Comment: I am certain that I missed a handful of other questions, e.g. questions talking about power sets and not directly about $\aleph$ numbers. But they are out there.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Aleph number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If by $\{ \aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, \dots \}$ you mean $\{ \aleph_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, then this set is countable because it's indexed by the natural numbers. However, this set doesn't contain $\aleph_{\omega}$ or any larger alephs.

If by $\{ \aleph_0, \aleph_1, \aleph_2, \dots \}$ you mean 'the set[sic] of all (well-orderable) cardinals', then it's certainly not countable; in fact, it's too big to be a set! (Hence the 'sic'.) There is an aleph for each ordinal $\alpha$, and [there are class-many ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burali-Forti_paradox).

It should also be noted that, unless you accept the generalised continuum hypothesis, it is not necessarily the case that $\aleph_{\alpha} = |\mathscr{P}^{\alpha}(\mathbb{N})|$ for all $\alpha$, as you suggest in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Clive Newstead's answer is absolutely correct I would just like to add a short addendum with regards to the second phrasing of your question using power sets.

As Clive already pointed out the "set" of $\{\aleph_0,\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\cdots\}$ need not have almost anything to do with the "set" $\{\omega,\mathscr{P}(\omega),\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\omega)),\cdots\}$. Though the second expression seems more likely to be interpreted as an actual set i.e. $\{\mathscr{P}^n(\omega);\;n\in\omega\}$ due to the fact that you have to introduce a new type of operation to interpret it as anything else. You can't iterate the power set operation more then an arbitrary **finite** number of times. At some point you have to take a union.

This is a standard convention, where it makes sense, to define  $\mathscr{P}^\alpha$ for $\alpha\geq\omega$  by the standard recursion approach if $\alpha$ is a limit then $\mathscr{P}^\alpha(\omega)=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathscr{P}^\beta(\omega)$ and when $\alpha=\beta+1$ you just have $\mathscr{P}^\alpha(\omega)=\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}^\beta(\omega))$.

Post script:
Becoming quite curious as to how much distance you can put between the two sets you mention I asked a question of my own to which Asaf Karagila kindly provided an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1867505/176997). To summarize assuming ZFC the second class is a subset of the first class but can easily be quite "thin" in it (for example you can make $\mathscr{P}(\omega)> \aleph_\kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the first ordinal such that $\aleph_\kappa=\kappa$).

If you drop choice, then it is consistent that the only thing the two classes have in common is $\omega=\aleph_0$.